# UnauthorizedAccessException on MediaElement in DatagramSocket.ReceivedMessage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

I want start my mediaElement (instance of MediaElement class) at when first pack of data came. So I wrote it like that.

```
private void SocketOnMessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (isPaused) return;

            if (!isStarted)
            {
                mediaElement.Play();
                isStarted = true;
            }

            var r = args.GetDataReader();
            var l = r.UnconsumedBufferLength;
            var buff = new byte[l];
            r.ReadBytes(buff);

            if (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff, 0, buff.Length) != "stop")
            {
                AudioSteam.AddBytes(buff);
            }
            else
            {
                mediaElement.Pause();
                isStarted = false;
                Debug.WriteLine("stop");
            }
            buff = null;

        }
```

Of course elier I set source for mediaElement (MediaStreamSource).

```
var socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.MessageReceived += SocketOnMessageReceived;
await socket.BindServiceNameAsync("4444");
HostName multicast = new HostName("230.0.0.1");
socket.JoinMulticastGroup(multicast);
isPaused = true;
isStarted = false;
AudioSteam = new Sine440AudioStreamSource(44100);
mdiaElement.SetSource(AudioSteam);
```

At first I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` then `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` at mediaElement.Start(); I have no idea why.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turns out that `DatagramSocket.ReceivedMessage` method is running at other thread so If you want access variables out of method scope you need to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>{
                      //Code
                    });
```

All in all I resign for that approach.